# Updating multiple documents by id using robo mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

So based on my research on SO i can use `$in` operator to update or find multiple documents in mongo db.

I am using Robo Mongo to run queries. The query below returns 4 documents as expected

`db.getCollection('workunits_old').find({_id:{$in:[31255225914.0,31255225898.0,31255566710.0,31255498298.0]}})`

[image]

However, when i use the same `$in` operator with `update`, it only updates the first record

`db.getCollection('workunits_old').update({_id:{$in:[31255225914.0,31255225898.0,31255566710.0,31255498298.0]}},{$unset:{isTransformed:""}})`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to pass `multi: true` option to update or you need to use `updateMany` for updating multiple documents
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/